# Add remote SFTP upload functionality to generated CSV-file through PHP

Tags: php, csv, ftp, sftp

I have a HTML form containing variables which are passed to a php file to generate a CSV file. This is working and once form is submitted it downloads the generated CSV file. However, I would like the CSV file to be uploaded to a remote SFTP server instead of beeing downloaded when submit action is made.

This is my current php file:

```
<?php
//give a filename
$filename = "order.csv";

//set headers to download file
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');            

//set the column names
$cells[] = array(
  'address', 
  'city', 
  'phone', 
  'email' );

//pass all the form values
$cells[] = array(
  $_POST['address'],
  $_POST['city'],
  $_POST['phone'],
  $_POST['email']);

foreach($cells as $cell){
    fputcsv($file,$cell);
}

fclose($file);  
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking to add it to your hosting server, or a remote server? For the former you can just store the file http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: I would like to store it to a remote server

Comment: How to do that is shown in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will try this out